# silviomoreto bootstrap select - fire event on click

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

This is properly an easy question, but I can't find a answer anywhere or get it to work.

Im using http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/ plugin.

How can I fire an event when people adds or removes a item on the list? I have tried with jquery click function and change function like this:

```
$([data-khtype=selectpicker]).click(function()
{
alert('test');
});
```

This is my select

```
<select data-khtype="selectpicker" multiple data-selected-text-format="count>1" data-width="120px">
<option>test</option>
<option>test2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: the user actually is clicking a mask not the select tag

Comment: @bto.rdz so how can I fire an event when the user is clicking? Can you show me an example or some documentation:-D? Cant find it myself

Comment: try with the change event

Comment: @Yann86 - with change event, do you mean $().change(function(){});? I have tried this, but it does not work:-(

Comment: Have made it work with the change event. My problem was the way I loaded selectpicker